Error When Compiling LaTeX Document in TeXstudio with Glossaries and Bibliographies in a Separate Build Directory
I am trying to manage the compilation of a LaTeX document using TeXstudio, aiming to keep all compiled files (like .log, .aux, .pdf, etc.) in a nested build folder to keep the root directory clean. However, I am encountering an issue related to the makeglossaries command not finding the main.acn file. Here are my settings and what I have tried:
TeXstudio Settings:

Commands Configuration:

pdflatex: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=build %.tex
biber: biber.exe --output-directory=build %
makeindex: makeindex.exe .\build\%.nlo -s .\build\%.idx -o .\build\%.nls
makeglossaries: makeglossaries.exe -d build %


Build Configuration:

Log and PDF files set to build folder under "Additional Search Paths" (from here)



I also attempted to use latexmk:

Commands: latexmk.exe -pdf -silent -synctex=1 -outdir=build %
Changed "Default Compiler" to "Latexmk"

Command Line Compilation:
The following sequence works when run directly from the command line:
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=build main.tex
makeglossaries -d build main
biber.exe --output_directory=build main

Issue:
Despite these settings, TeXstudio throws the following error:
Input index file main.acn not found. Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]

Question:
How can I adjust my TeXstudio settings to ensure that the makeglossaries command locates the main.acn file and compiles the document correctly, while keeping all auxiliary files in the build directory?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
P.S. the command
makeindex -s build/main.ist -t build/main.glg -o build/main.gls build/main.glo

works perfectly from the command line:
This is makeindex, version 2.16 [MiKTeX 24.4].
Scanning style file ./build/main.ist...........................done (27 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file build/main.acn....done (300 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries.....done (2757 comparisons).
Generating output file build/main.acr....done (106 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in build/main.acr.
Transcript written in build/main.alg.

but placing makeindex -s build/%.ist -t build/%.alg -o build/%.acr build/%.acn in the configuration doesn't help.

Do yourself a favour and don't use a build directory. Much better for one's sanity.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes, I understand. I often receive this feedback. However, I prefer to continue using the build folder. Old habits die hard, and with my background in compiled languages like C/Fortran, I find a cluttered code base intolerable. Experience has taught me that cleanups can be pretty risky; I've inadvertently deleted crucial files while tidying up the root folder by hand. Besides, it's aesthetically displeasing.

If you want to avoid all these problems, compile in the build folder. There are tools like ltx2any which will automatically do this for you.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I do. I actually contributed to the project a while ago. But I did not think of using it with Texstudio. Will look into that.

BTW: l3build can also be used to just generate documents instead of building packages. And alternatively TeXstudio also provides a (configurable) cleanup: Tools → Cleanup Auxiliary Files

@Foad TeXstudio has the option to define "User Commands" in the "Build" tab of the preferences. This way one can use ltx2any like any other compilation chain in texstudio

I value the alternative methods proposed, but I would prefer if we could attempt the primary approach before abandoning it.  Could you guide me on how to execute makeindex from the terminal to explore the problem and diagnose the issue?

well the error is about the main.acn not about main.glo so it doesn't help much to tests command line versions which uses the glo, you need to check if the acn is where the commands expect it. Beside this: it is wrong to apply C or fortran habitudes here. LaTeX is different as output files are also real input files. Copy your files in a build folder with l3build if you want a clean source directory.

@UlrikeFischer, The main.acn file is in the build folder. How can I verify in TeXstudio where it is expecting the file? Which command should I use next in the cmd terminal?

I have no idea. I neither use texstudio nor a build folder - I have decided long time ago that my time is too precious for such a setup. Generally I simply ignore the auxilliary files and store the real files in a clean git. In places where I want a clean build setup, I setup a l3build system.

I do not do this and would not do this. My project files are scattered, but the only generated files not in the main directory are image related (memoize or external). TeX isn't make. However, if it works on the command line, I assume you can configure TeX Studio to do it. makeglossaries is just a wrapper as far as I know. There's no reason you can't use makeindex directly in TS if you want to. I'm surprised you lost critical files doing clean up. Surely you use some kind of version control?
